# Why Particles Look Noise in Fluid Simulation

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

Why do particles move like glitter every frame?
I hope it doesn't sparkle like noise, but it's still rolling. It's not a material problem, it's a fluid area problem.
Resizing a domain or resizing a flow is not the only problem to be solved. I think it's because the particles in the fluid are designated as aggregates and every frame changes to a different particle

**blender file at [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K4H9zFClFeYX_H_svxL72bFqErmBcb4-?usp=sharing)**

//

//
[image]

Comment: Actually the particles of the fluid simulation are mainly used by the simulation as a base for creating a fluid mesh, you can render them with e.g. spheres instanced on them to make them visible. But it will not look as if you were pouring thousands of balls in a bowl...

Comment: I uploaded the gif file again. Can I help you understand the problem a little?

Comment: I understand what your problem is with this, but as I said earlier: the particles of the fluid simulation are not working like for example a rigid body simulation of a bunch of spheres. As a Mantaflow fluid simulation it looks absolutely normal to me. You are also saying it is not a material problem - I have no idea and cannot see how the material is set up on those spheres so I do not know how they are supposed to look like.

Comment: I want to do something that looks natural even when I designate particles like this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMKoCI6UeI0&t=231s). The only difference between this video and my work is that the particles are collection, object

Comment: Now that's an important information missing in the question. As I said, a fluid simulation is not like other simulations. Not even like regular particle animations. When you use a collection, each fluid particle gets a new object assigned per frame. They do not stay consistent after "being born" like regular particles. So you cannot use different particles in a fluid simulation if you want them to stay the same throughout the simulation. By the way, I'm sure there are more differences to the video. For example, it does not look as if you have set the _Narrow Band Width_ to 10.